# Why is the image not displaying on GitHub when using ![]() with a local file path in R Markdown .md file?

Tags: r, image, github, r-markdown

**Problem description**

I am facing an issue with displaying an image on GitHub using R Markdown (`.md`) files. I have included the image in my document using the following syntax:

```markdown
![](file:///C:/Users/Username/Desktop/image.jpg)
```

However, when I view the R Markdown (`.md`) file, the image appears broken. I have double-checked the file path, and it seems correct. The image file is located on my desktop.

**Troubleshooting steps**

1. Verified that the file path is accurate.
2. Checked the image file format and confirmed it is supported (e.g., `.jpg, .png`).
3. Attempted to use relative paths instead of an absolute path.
4. Checked for typos or syntax errors in the Markdown file.

Despite these efforts, the image is not displaying as expected on GitHub. Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzIca.jpg)

I knit my file and images were showing on my local file.

But it is not showing in `.md` file in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub cannot access files that are stored locally on your own computer.
You have to add the picture to your github project or upload it somewhere else (e.g. imgur) and use this weblink in your markdown.